# RavenDb DeleteByIndex on nested collection condition

Tags: ravendb

Assume that I have a schema as below:

```
Father { // Type: 1
   Id
}

Mother { // Type: 2
   Id
}
Child {
  Parents: [
    { ParentId, ParentType } // ParentType could be 1 or 2 acording to entity's type
  ]
}
```

How could I create an index that allow us to DeleteByIndex and accept lucene query such as: "Parents,ParentId:xyz AND Parents,ParentType:2"?

As I tried to create index as below:

```
Map = views => from view in views
  select new
  {
    view.ParentId,
    view.ParentType,
    view.Parents
  }
```

RavenDb failed to delete and said that "Parents,ParentId" is not indexed yet.
The reason for doing that is I would like to delete all children data when it is a child of one of {Mother, Father}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `Parents,ParentId` is only applicable for dynamic indexes, using a static index, you are defining the field names, and you can name them however you want.

```
Map = views => from view in views
  from parent in view.Parents
  select new
  {
    parent .ParentId,
    parent .ParentType
  }
```

But check the docs about what fanout indexes if your system can have many parents.